# Unable to add projects while setting server in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, debugging, eclipse-plugin

Eclipse could not detect my maven projects while adding projects in server. The projects icon is not seems to be regular one. PFB the screen shot.

[image]

Below are option I tried ,

- Right click on project and selected Project Facet and made sure Dynamic Web module is selected and Java modules are checked but could not select runtimes on right side panel as below

[image] - Is this expected behavior ?

- Tried to switch other version of Dynamic Web module and reverted back to 3.0
- Project build and clean
- Restarted many times
- Tried with other versions of eclipse
- Tried with creating new workspace
- Tried with deleting created server and created fresh server
- Updated maven projects
- Tried with other version of eclipse, 1. Neon, Luna, 2020

But none of the above worked. Has anyone faced similar problem ? if yes could you please help me to resolve this problem?

Comment: What server instance were you trying to deploy to, and what kind of server runtimes have you configured? Do you have m2e-wtp installed? Skip Luna and Neon versions--they're from 2014 and 2016. Always use the current release.

Comment: I am trying to setup AEM server(Adobe Experience Manager). Tried with current eclipse venison but is not working